# Excel cells share the same memory address

Tags: vba, excel

I am checking memory addresses for Excel cells using undocumented function ObjPtr. I am surprised to find that different cells can share the same address in memory. It doesn't make sense... Can someone explain this weird thing?

```
Sub testobjptr()

Dim objTest As Range
Set objTest = Range("A1")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print Join(Split(objTest.Address, "$"), "") & " at " & ObjPtr(objTest)
    Set objTest = objTest.Offset(i, i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the output in immediate window:

A1 at 80276608

B2 at 80276928

D4 at 80276608

G7 at 80276928

K11 at 80276608

P16 at 80276928

V22 at 80276608

AC29 at 80276928

AK37 at 80276608

AT46 at 80276928

Comment: Do the cells with the same address share the same values?

Answer (score 3):

> I am surprised to find that different cells can share the same address in memory.

No. Different cells are not sharing the same address in memory. The object `objTest` is. **A pointer is created each time a variable is assigned.**

Try this. Here you will see that all objects reference to the same cell but is allocated a different address in memory.

```
Sub testobjptr()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = Range("A1")
    Set rng3 = Range("A1")
    Set rng4 = Range("A1")

    Debug.Print Join(Split(rng1.Address, "$"), "") & " at " & ObjPtr(rng1)
    Debug.Print Join(Split(rng2.Address, "$"), "") & " at " & ObjPtr(rng2)
    Debug.Print Join(Split(rng3.Address, "$"), "") & " at " & ObjPtr(rng3)
    Debug.Print Join(Split(rng4.Address, "$"), "") & " at " & ObjPtr(rng4)
End Sub
```

Output

```
A1 at 202834688
A1 at 260111360
A1 at 260111744
A1 at 260091264
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Set objTest = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print objTest.Address & " at " & ObjPtr(objTest)
    Set objTest = Range("A2")
    Debug.Print objTest.Address & " at " & ObjPtr(objTest)
    Set objTest = Range("A3")
    Debug.Print objTest.Address & " at " & ObjPtr(objTest)
Next i
```

You will see that also in this case the address oscillates between two values to Range("A1") will be once the first and the other time the other address. What you get is not the address of the cell but of a VBA 'Range' object which can represent one cell but can also represent a couple of cells. Why this value is oscillating is a matter of the hidden implementation but is not the place in memory where Excel stores the value of a special cell.